# What is the shitah of the Rambam regarding mevarekh mossi havero [מברך מוציא חברו]?

Tags: blessing, rambam, motzi-yedei-chovato

**Before asking the question, I need to give some background information**:

The Rambam in Hilkhoth Berakhoth 1:11 says,

כָּל הַשּׁוֹמֵעַ בְּרָכָה מִן הַבְּרָכוֹת מִתְּחִלָּתָהּ וְעַד סוֹפָהּ, וְנִתְכַּוַּן לָצֵאת בָּהּ יְדֵי חוֹבָתוֹ--יָצָא, וְאַף עַל פִּי שֶׁלֹּא עָנָה אָמֵן

Translation:

"Everyone who hears a *berakhah* from [any of the categories] of *berakhoth* from its beginning to its end, and intends thereby to fulfill his own obligation, has fulfilled his obligation, and [it is so] even if he did not answer *Amen*."

It is apparently assumed that the Rambam is of the opinion, expressed in the Shulhan Arukh (cf. Orah Hayyim 213:3), that in order for the listener to be *yossei yedhei hovatho* he must not only hear every word of the *berakhah* being recited, but the one reciting it (the *mevarekh*) must also have the specific intention of being *mossi yedhei hovatho*. Basically implying that both the *mevarekh* and the one listening to him (the *shomea*) must have made some sort of agreement beforehand that each would have the other in mind. However, from the plain reading of the Mishneh Torah, it would seem that Rambam holds that the intention to fulfill one's obligation is only required on the part of the one who hears. Further, no mention is made of the *mevarekh* and the *shomea* making prior arrangements to have each other in mind.

Anyone who is familiar with the style of the Rambam knows the he says what says and what he doesn't say he doesn't say. In other words, if the Rambam makes no mention of the requirement of intention on the part of *mevarekh*, then it would seem that he does not hold it to be necessary for the *shomea* to fulfill his obligation. This is the general rule, with the exception of some cases - such as *natilath yadhoyim* where the entirety of *halakhoth* regarding it are found in Hilkhoth Berakhoth 6, with the exception of the *halakhah* of being *meshafshef* ones hands, which is found all the way toward the end of the Mishneh Torah in Hilkhoth Miqwa'oth 11:2(3). So, if anyone knows of another place in the Rambam which speaks about this halakhic subject, please let me know.

In researching this halakhah in the Rambam, I have read the available *nosei kelim* (which are the Kesef Mishneh and the Migdal Oz in this case), the *pirush* by Rav Yohai Maqbili shlit"a, the *pirush* of Mori Yusef (Rav Yosef Kapah) z"l, the Shu"T HaRambam, the Shu"T Rav Yehoshua HaNagidh, and the various Shu"Tim of Rav Ratzon Arusi shlit"a. In all of this I found that NONE of them discussed this question at all, with the exception of Rav Arussi who did not bring any textual support from the Rambam for the requirement of intention on the part of the *mevarekh* to be *mossi* the *shomea*, rather he said that *le-aniyuth da`ato* he held that it was required. Other than this, I have not found anyone who expresses an answer making an argument from the text of the Mishneh Torah itself.

One further piece of information: In Hil. Berakhoth 1:15 the Rambam states that we do not answer "Amen" after a child who is merely reciting *berakhoth* while learning. He then states  וְהָעוֹנֶה אַחֲרֵיהֶן אָמֵן, לֹא יָצָא יְדֵי חוֹבָתוֹ ("And the one who does answer *Amen* [after the *berakhah* of a child reciting *berakhoth* for the sake of learning them] ***does not fulfill his obligation***"). It would seem from this statement that the Rambam is dealing with a *hava mina* (assumption; pre-conceived notion) that intention is required only on the part of the *shomea* to fulfill his obligation but not on the part of the *mevarekh* since it is clear that a *tinoq shel beth rabban* (schoolchild) does not have the *da`ath* required to be *mossi yedhei hovatho*. It seems as if the Rambam is answering this *hava mina* by saying, "Your assumption is correct that intention is only required by the *shomea*, but this principle will not work in this particular case."

**Question**:

Does the Rambam hold that both the one who recites a *berakhah* and the one who listens BOTH need to have the other in mind in order for the one listening to fulfill his obligation thereby? Sources are greatly appreciated!

Comment: sholom 3aleicham wara7aeem ubarocho shal Alloheem a7ee. i was going to ask if you read mori gafe7's peirush but seems like you answered that question for me further down in your post. isnt it somewhat reasonable to assume that a shalia7 9ibbur is taking upon himself to keep in mind all the other people of the meenyan because it is his job to be a representative for the entire meenyan before HaShem while we ourselves are just the "back up crew" of the representative. and by saying omein, we agree to what the representative has to say in our name.

Comment: therefore it is a given that the shalia7 9ibbur has in mind everyone in the meenyan, and it is up to you to agree to him "representing you spiritually" by saying omein and like Rabbeinu says without saying omein as well. but in regards to a kid, he is not your shalia7 for learning and therefore you should recite your own barocho.

Comment: I would respond by saying that we are still in a similar quandry since the Rambam does not specifically state the requirement for the mevarekh to have a specific intention to be mossi the shomea. Added to that, what if someone comes in late to davening and the Shaliah Ssibbur is unaware that he joined the minyan, then can the person be yossei yedhei hova thereby? Your reasoning makes sense, but where is it in the text that Rabbenu requires it? Thank you so much for responding. Shavua` Tov.

Comment: if there is 100people in the meenyan, the shalia7 9ibbur needs to know each person's name and address and keep him in mind when he goes up to be the shalia7? i dont think so. it is a concept which is more metaphorical and not a literal concept. as in the shalia7 9ibur should keep in mind everyone in the meenyan as in the entire meenyan and not every person individually. so if a person came late, he is still part of the meenyan which the shalia7 9ibur is representing.

Comment: @Maimonist, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for laying out the work you've already done on this.

Comment: therefore if a person doesnt want to be yo9ei even though he is in the beith hakannasath praying with the meenyan, the shalia7 has "him" in mind but he could keep in mind that he wants to represent himself. i do this many times when i am praying in a non baladi shul or if the shul i am in is not davening al pi halocho.

Comment: @Maimonist hilchoth tafillo chp 8 halocho 9-10.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob What about Brachot that are not being said by a Sha"tz? What if I say Shehakol loudly on my beverage and someone behind me says Amen and drinks their beverage as well?

Comment: @DoubleAA i know for hamo9ee, one is yo9ei because that is how a it is done normally. the ba3l habayeeth breaks the bread and gives over to others. but i am not sure a shahacol works like that. since the RaMbaM explicitly says a shalia7 is only for those who dont know how to pray. but if you can, it is best you say it yourself.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYa3gob What about if I say Hamotzi on my bread alone in a room and a guy next door who I don't know exists hears me and says amen? This question is so much broader than your examples where there is a certain traditional structure and assumed assumptions.

Comment: @DoubleAA it would seem to me, in all the cases in which there is a type of "leader" in a certain action being done, that is the one in which you can benefit from in regards to a barocho. but individual things are not so. i am not sure. i didnt learn the whole thing in regards to this topic so dont rely on me. i am nobody

Comment: @DoubleAA my friend said an interesting thing once when i was eating by him. he said that lets say the family comes and sits at the table and the father makes qiddush. if the father keeps in mind that he doesnt want anyone to be yo9ei his qiddush he can do so. yes it will be a dumb thing to do because what benefit is there so such a thing. but it is totally possible. so i assume that both parties need to keep in mind that you are yo9ei from one to the other. so if a random guy heard you say a barocho and you didnt have him in mind then no he doesnt benefit from it i would think.

Comment: but if you were making a shahacol for everyone in the room and a random guy just happened to step in i think he would get it. but if he was not in the room he wouldnt get unless the yid making the barocho had in mind everyone who wants to be yo9ei me can be yo9e and not only in the room.

Comment: [Shofar 2:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/3602.htm#4) may be relevant.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20022&st=&pgnum=65

Comment: @DoubleAA - As always, you have given me something that I had not possessed before. And, as always, you have done this with respect, erudition, and few words. HaShem yishmor `alekha. Kol tuv.